# Find eigenvalues from characterestic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Equation of A : $λ^2 + 4λ - 12 = 0$ 
Find eigen values of $A$ and $A^3$
Find expression of $A^{-1}$ in terms of A
I have no idea how to start solving it

Comment: The equation is simple to solve. You can start with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume the statement is that $A$ is a 2 by 2 matrix with $p(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I_2 -A) = \lambda^2+4 \lambda -12$? The roots ($-6$ and $2$) are the eigenvalues.

Eigenvalues behave nice when taking powers so if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda^3$ is an eigenvalue of $A^3$, etc... Do you need a proof?

The last part is less trivial, I believe.
The Hamilton-Cayley theorem tells us that $p(A) = A^2 +4A -12 \; I_2 = 0_2$ (the two by 2 zero matrix on the RHS). From this we see that $A + 4 I - 12 A^{-1}=0$, whence $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{12} A + \frac{1}{3}I$.

Answer (score 1):

By $λ^2 + 4λ - 12 = 0$, $λ = 2  $ or $λ = -6  $

Through [diagonalization](http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/diagonal/diagonal.html), A is similar to D= \begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 0\\ 
0 & -6
\end{bmatrix}

$A^3$ is similar to $D^3$ =  \begin{bmatrix} 
8 & 0\\ 
0 & -216
\end{bmatrix}

So eigenvalue for $A^3$ is $8 $ and $-216$ .